# "But" vs. "However" to draw a contrast

Tags: adverbs, coordination

I wrote this sentence which is too long with "but"

> To illustrate this, suppose we want to eliminate the navigation bar from the page sidebar. We may create a rule in which the link density is employed to distinguish such a part, **but** when this rule is applied to the page, all such elements are removed regardless of their locations in the page, even if they are within the main content (e.g. Table of Contents)

can I write it with "however"? I just feel **but** in this sentence makes more direct contrast.

Are there cases in which we'd better use "but" even in formal sentences?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, you should normally start a new sentence before ***however***, and follow it with a comma. Also note that since ***such a part*** is obviously intimately bound to something mentioned in even earlier text, if you actually *like* the idea of using long sentences it might make more sense to attach those first 17 words to the *preceding* sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers lol, 17 words!

Comment: Erm... Even with your edit now giving the preceding sentence, I still don't understand what this ***part*** is, or what specific characteristic makes it ***such a** part*. If in fact you mean *parts such as navigation bars* (and assuming *distinguish = unambiguously identify*), I'm not sure the phrasing is particularly idiomatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **part** is the *navigation bar* and having many links within make it **such a part**. is it conveyed?

Comment: The fact that you mention "link density" doesn't mean it makes sense to immediately reference some particular (unspecified) density indirectly through ***such a***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I just think the phrasing is confusing. Apparently *such a part* initially and specifically refers to the navigation bar - the part with such a [very high?] link density. But then within the very same sentence you go on to reference *all such elements* in such a way as to make it clear *such* here doesn't in fact pin things down very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*But* and *however*, though they both imply a contrast between what goes before and what comes after, focus the relationship very differently.

- *but* itself takes a low emphasis: it is unstressed in speech, and in writing accommodates low-disjunction pointing—it may follow a mere comma or in some circumstances no point at all. Even in high-disjunction contexts it throws the emphasis on the following proposition rather than on the contrast between the two propositions. *But* is typically used to introduce a clause which qualifies, mitigates or dismisses the previous clause.
- *however* at the beginning of a clause takes high emphasis. In speech it takes a primary stress, which is usually not matched until considerably later in the following clause. In writing it must be preceded by high-disjunction pointing—a semicolon, dash or full stop. It emphasizes the contrast between the two propositions it lies between, and typically signals that your discourse is going in a new direction.

  This emphasis is somewhat neutralized when *however* appears as a parenthetical at some point after the beginning of the clause. It usually appears as a 'drop-off' after the clause's first primary stress and marks the stressed element as the source or occasion of contrast.

In your sentence, then, the use of *but* or *however* will depend on how you regard the contrast between the propositions to either side. <s>Since we don't know what point you are illustrating, or how the contrast within your example bears on it, it's impossible to say which you should use.</s>

ADDED:
Your comment adds that "when the rule is applied, unexpectedly, the user see many other elements are also erased from the page." This situation, where your key point is the unexpected difference between what was intended and what actually happened, seems to me to be tailor-made for *however*; and I'd rewrite a little to make the contrast even clearer:

> To illustrate this, suppose we want to eliminate the navigation bar from the page sidebar. We create a rule in which the link density is employed to distinguish that piece. That will certainly remove the navigation bar; **however**, when the rule is applied to the entire page **all** such elements will be removed, regardless of location on the page—even elements (for example, a Table of Contents) within the main content.

The pieces in boldface are those which receive primary stress in speech.

Comment: Thank you much for your complete answer. As you see in the paragraph I am describing a scenario in which user does something (defines a rule) and expects something to happen (to remove a certain part of the page) but when the rule is applied, unexpectedly, the user see many other elements are also erased from the page. Now, how can I express such a contrast? However or but?!

Comment: @Ahmad -- see my addition

Answer (score 1):

In technical and scientific writing, prefer '*however*' over '*but*'.  Their meaning is the same, and yet the reading seems smoother with the former, while the latter creates a harder point.

The use of '*but*' is more suited for idioms like "*all **but** one*".

Comment: I agree with Fingers, avoid such long sentences in technical and scientific writing.

Comment: Can I use "however" like this: "*We may create a rule in which the link density is employed to distinguish such a part. When this rule is applied to the page, **however**, all such elements are removed regardless of their locations in the page, even if they are within the main content (e.g. Table of Contents).*"

Comment: Certainly, yes.  In that case 'however' is a lead-in word placed after the introductory subordinate clause.